# In tcsh, how do I disable spelling correction of my command?

Tags: linux, tcsh

Recently, when we updated our OS, we got a new tcsh feature enabled by default.  Whenever I type a command that tcsh doesn't recognize, I get an annoying spelling correction like:

```
% cats

CORRECT>cast (y|n|e|a)?
```

I want to disable this feature and allow misspellings to error out like:

```
% cats
cats: Command not found.
```

Is my <kbd>enter</kbd> key somehow getting re-bound?  What could be causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this same problem.  You want to add

```
set correct=command
```

to your `.cshrc`.  This will allow commands to be completed, but not corrected.